# subdomain with www. on second place not working

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a problem with my domains. Until a few months ago this worked fine, but since some time I cannot resolve a domain whenever there is a `www.` at second place, for exampple:

```
subdomain.www.example.com
```

is not working, while all other combinations work, like

```
www.subdomain.example.com
a.b.example.com
www.example.com
example.com
```

It's the same with all domains at my hoster [candan](https://www.candan.eu/)

Is it possible something changed worldwide in the resolution with domains that have a www. in the middle?

In my case http://manual.spacetrace.com/ works correctly (redirect), but http://manual.www.spacetrace.com/ not

these are my configs:

```
ServerName manual.spacetrace.com
Redirect / http://www.spacetrace.org/man/
```

and

```
ServerName manual.www.spacetrace.org
Redirect / http://www.spacetrace.org/man/
```

If I try something, I haven't configured, I get a (correct) response from my server, for example: `manual.xxx.spacetrace.com`. Only `www` in the middle makes a problem.

## A-Records at candan.eu

```
Hostname    IPv4
www         213.123.123.123
@           213.123.123.123
mail        213.123.123.123
*           213.123.123.123
localhost   213.123.123.123
```

Comment: No. You just have broken zone (and|or expectation). Show it (plus your own knowledge of hostmastering internals, which I can't detect now - because you mix in a heap `hostname` and `(sub)domain`)

Comment: "Is it possible something changed worldwide in the resolution with domains that have a www. in the middle?" No. Is this all domains, or just a specific one you control?

Comment: http://manual.spacetrace.com/ works correctly (redirect), but http://manual.www.spacetrace.com/ not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> manual.spacetrace.com works correctly (redirect), but manual.www.spacetrace.com not

You don't have a DNS record set up for `manual.www.spacetrace.com`:

```
$ dig manual.spacetrace.com 

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;manual.spacetrace.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
manual.spacetrace.com.  3599    IN  A   213.239.220.106
```

versus:

```
$ dig manual.www.spacetrace.com 

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;manual.www.spacetrace.com. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
spacetrace.com.     1799    IN  SOA ns1.can02.de. robotdns.canhost.de. 2010072601 14400 3600 604800 86400
```

Setting up `foo.example.com` doesn't mean `foo.www.example.com` is magically also set up. They're separate FQDNs - you'll need to create records for each.

*side note: I've never seen anyone access `foo.example.com` as `foo.www.example.com`. `www.foo.example.com`, yes.*

Comment: I use froxlor which should handle this, shouldn't it? Or is this a problem of my hoster? Who is setting up the DNS? And why is `manual.xxx.spacetrace.com` working correctly?

Comment: `manual.xxx.spacetrace.com` working likely means you have a wildcard `*.spacetrace.com` DNS entry. The `www.spacetrace.com` entry takes precedence over the wildcard. I can't answer the question of who sets up DNS, but your domain's WHOIS output shows Candan as your DNS provider. Presumably their backend has a DNS console somewhere for you to tinker with.

Comment: I added the A-Records to my Question. Do I have to remove the record for `www.`?

Comment: @rubo77 That should do the trick. You can also get rid of the `mail` and `localhost` ones, as they'll all be covered by the wildcard as well.

Comment: cool, that worked I deleted the `www` entry (I left `mail` because I am afraid, some mail programs could stop working without)